# If else condition in iReport

Tags: if-statement, jasper-reports, ternary-operator

I want to add "-" symbole if the field is empty. How can I do this in iReport?

Answer (score 1):

You can use ternary operator(?:) instead of "if".

Try setting following code to Text Field Expression.

```
(($F{YOUR_FIELD} != "")? $F{YOUR_FIELD}: "-")
```

Comment: Thank you brother. Yes it's working. Thanks a lot. (Y)